# Deformation theory introduction without unnecessary machinery

Tags: algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

I would like to find an introduction (book, article and/or lecture course) in deformation theory that does not use unnecessary machinery (for example, schemes instead of complex varietie, or deformations over general artinian rings instead of first-order deformations), but explains some simple ideas. For example, how $Ext^1(E, E)$ is connected with tangent space to deformation space of vector bundles in point $E$, whatever that may mean. It should probably ignore proves of technical details at all. Could you recommend me something?

Comment: In order to do deformation theory in a reasonable way you need to introduce nilpotent elements, i.e. either schemes or complex analytic spaces. Otherwise you only see first order deformations. In the book by Kodaira - "Complex manifolds and deformation of complex structures" - first order deformation theory is developed, and only complex manifolds are used. I don't think he discusses deformations of vector bundles though.

Comment: @Rieux, I meant using deformations of varieties, but not more general schemes, to avoid nilpotents, non-noetherianness and other technicalities. But probably you are right about first order deformations, as artinian rings seem to be a bit to heavy machinery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost a year later, I found the necessary part of deformation theory clearly explained in the beginning of [Hartshorne *Lectures on Deformation Theory*](https://math.berkeley.edu/~robin/math274root.pdf). See my question [MO:253578](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/253578/) for details.